# Xamarin-Is it possible to use Xlab in SharedProject

Tags: xamarin.forms, xlabs

I want to use XLAB Nugget in a shared project but i could not find "Add Nuget" option in shared project.

Any Clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/). You don't have references in a shared project. A shared project is included as a reference in another project (which would contain your XLabs reference).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I added the reference to Droid Project but it is still not accessible in XAML (Xamarin Project)

Comment: @Brijesh You're going to have to post some code before I can help you. Have you added the xlabs namespace reference? 
`xmlns:labs="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"`
and then `<labs:ExtendedEntry x:Name="entry"/>`